# Da dove viene la 'boiata'

Tags: etymology

Una ***[boiata](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=boiata)*** è un'espressione informale che significa:

> - cosa fatta male, malriuscita: quel film è una boiata
> - frase sciocca, stupida | (non com.) azione indegna e scorretta

Controllando l'origine della parola, il dizionario Garzanti dice:

> - Etimologia: ← deriv. di boia.

Quale può essere il nesso tra un termine come ***[boia](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=boia)*** (chi esegue le condanne capitali) e boiata, il cui significato non sembra richiamare la crudezza della definizione di boia?

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/boiata/) dà una diversa origine: «dal milan. *boiada*, propr. «abbaiamento, latrato», der. di *boià*, var. di *baià*, «abbaiare»; cfr. baiata» (e una baiata è uno «Schiamazzo fatto per canzonatura o scherno contro qualcuno» oppure una «Sciocchezza, discorso senza senso»).

Invece il Devoto-Oli, lo Zingarelli e il classico dizionario etimologico Battisti-Alessio danno tutti come origine la derivazione da “boia”, senza ulteriori spiegazioni. Il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/boiata) è appena più cauto, con «forse der. di boia».

Il Cortelazzo-Zolli aggiunge altri considerazioni e un'altra possibilità: «Se il sentimento ling. com. può collegare *boiata* nella seconda accezione [cioè “cosa fatta o riuscita molto male”] con ‘(azione da) *boia*’ (DEI, come in realtà è per il rom. *bojerìa*, ‘ribalderia, furfanteria’: 1952 Prati *Pront.*), l'analisi ling. la porta, piuttosto, accanto al sett. *boiada*, che, dal senso primitivo di ‘pappolata’ (da *boj* ‘bollire’: p. es. nel piacentino: 1882, Foresti), è passata già nel parmigiano del 1856 (Malaspina) a ‘cosa vile e propria solo della plebe’ (...)». (Il DEI è il già citato Battisti-Alessio).

Comment: Strano no? A naso l'etimologia che dà il  Treccani sembra avere più senso.

Comment: @Josh61: Ho avuto modo di consultare il Cortelazzo-Zolli e ho aggiunto quello che si dice lì, che aggiunge qualcosa.

Answer (score 0):

Per *boiata* si può intendere *azione da boia*, ovviamente, per quanto faccia bene il suo lavoro, l'opera del boia non si può intendere come ben fatta.

Allo stesso modo può derivare il significato di azione scorretta.